# 61 10 status error in authenticate command using apdu

Tags: apdu

I am authenticating the USIM. The apdu command i am running is

```
0088 0081 22 10 %RAND 10 %AUTN
```

where rand is random number and autn is authentication token. 
On executing this command, I am getting status error 61 10. According to my knowledge, this status means 10 bytes are still available and are to be fetched using GET RESPONSE command. I tried doing that too but it didn't help. Please guide me on how to resolve this error.